# What else needed to improve my VMs?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I had my virtual machines up and running for months without any performance issues. Starting today, I noticed the hard drive was very busy reading (I/O) even though a VM was idle. I am on Dell Inspiron N5110. I tried the following steps from VMware but still no luck:

1. Converted the virtual hard drive (.vmdk) from growable to preallocated. (notice that growable worked for me for months with no issues)
2. Using the latest VMware version. (10.x)
3. Performed a couple of disk defrags for both the host and the guest.
4. Using 1 processor, 1 core per guest.
5. Updated my BIOS to the latest version.
6. Didn't change the virtualization engine settings and kept it as it is. (Automatic)

I don't know what else I need to do. I used to run 6 VMs at the same time with no issues. In fact, the issue came up right after the preallocated conversion. I am thinking to convert it back to growable but many people suggested the preallocated because it is faster. For me, it is a tortoise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of Windows-I'd-guess you're running, but I'd check:

- Enough memory?
- Enough free space on the hard drive?
- Is indexing service running?
- Is there an anti-virus program?  Is it updating?
- Are automatic Windows udpates enabled?
- Is it possible you are being accessed from an unwanted location, i.e. being used as an open relay for spam?

etc.

Take a look at the processes running when things seem busy, and sort by CPU usage.

Comment: I'd also check and make sure i have the latest VMWare tools up and running.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not showing this information. It is the typical Dell Inspiron specs: 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD, Intel Core i7 (8 cores). Antivirus is disabled intentionally by me, Automatic Updates is enabled but it is not updating or installing any updates while the VMs are running. As i mentioned, it is a disk I/O busy issue not CPU issue. I launched the Windows Performance Monitor to view the disk I/O performance and it is high but it is not showing which process is reading and writing.

Comment: Rusl, latest VMware tools is installed.

Comment: Ok, just for the record. I converted a virtual disk back to growable mode and guess what? It is working flawlessly. I don't understand because preallocated should be more faster since it is not performing calculations every time the disk is writing. I am going to try the other VMs now.